# Send smtp email with dynamic smtp options cakephp

Tags: email, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I can send email configuring smtp options from email.php file and it works fine. But I want to send emails, where the smtp options, like host, port, username and password are taken from database.

I tried to use this, but does not work, just gives an error `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`. The smtp options are correct.

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$Email = new CakeEmail('smtp');

$Email->smtpOptions = array(
    'host' => $smtpAccount['host'],
    'port' => $smtpAccount['port'],
    'username' => $smtpAccount['username'],
    'password' => $smtpAccount['password'],
);

$Email->to($email);
$Email->template('sending')->emailFormat('both');
$Email->subject($subject);
$Email->viewVars (
    array(
        'content' => $content
    )
);

return $Email->send();
```

trying to set the host like `$Email->host($smtpAccount['host'])`;
gives an error `Call to undefined method CakeEmail::host()`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `$Email->smtpOptions` should be used

```
$Email->config(array(
    'host' => $smtpAccount['host'],
    'port' => $smtpAccount['port'],
    'username' => $smtpAccount['username'],
    'password' => $smtpAccount['password'],
));
```

Comment: Note that you could also read the data from the DB in the `EmailConfig` class constructor [**as mentioned in the docs**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#configuration).